# Connecting Database with edmx

Tags: edmx

i have one .edmx file,which is connection string as below:

```
<add name="NeoSoftWindowApp_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NeoSoftDataEntity.csdl|res://*/NeoSoftDataEntity.ssdl|res://*/NeoSoftDataEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NeoFasWindowApp_db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

i attach my database in sql server 2008 sucessfully,
my project also build sucessfully,
but when i go to login,
i got the following error:
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}**

how to solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Instance right click on the server instance in the SQL Server management studio and go to the Properties and go to Connections and check Allow remote connections.

If this is not working let me know. :)